# Can't open file in Linux via 0x80

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to implement in GAS a simple test program which opens a file, writes to it some text and exits. However, the system call for 'open' keeps returning '-14' ("EFAULT - bad address" if I understand correctly). The program code is the following:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .data

textoutput:
    .asciz  "Hello world!"
pstr_end:
    .set lentext, pstr_end - textoutput
filetoopen:
    .asciz  "/tmp/tsttxt"

.section .text
.globl main

.func main
main:

mov eax, 5          #  open
mov ebx, filetoopen   # filname
mov ecx, 2            # flags: read and write
mov edx, 0700    # mode
int 0x80

mov ebx, eax      # <<< !!! eax here contains -14
mov eax, 4
mov ecx, textoutput
mov edx, lentext
int 0x80

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

The problem seems to be with the `filetoopen` string (the manpage to `open` says that EFAULT means `pathname points outside your accessible address space`.) Is the `filetoopen` declared properly in the program's code? What can be the cause of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: I would consider using YASM or NASM if you're going to be using Intel syntax for pure assembly programming. Their Intel syntax is "better".

Comment: @Jonathon I like that with GAS one can use Eclipse for working with assembler (syntax highlighting, debugging etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In intel syntax you need to use `mov ebx, offset filetoopen`.
If you look at the actual instruction as assembled you can see it's a memory load:

```
80483e1:       8b 1d 2d 96 04 08       mov    ebx,DWORD PTR ds:0x804962d
```

That is of course wrong, you need the address here. This applies to the other two occurrences of this pattern as well.

Comment: Thanks. 'lea' seems to be the correct instruction in this case.